# How to detach NSTextView's undo manager from NSDocument?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nsdocument

I have an NSDocument that is in a non-directly editable format, it's a description of something in XML. The NSWindow has a settings view controller associated with it which manipulates the data in the document just fine, undo works as expected, save, etc. Now also in the NSWindow is an NSTextView, which the user can enter some text into, but is not part of the content of the document, it's used only as temporary text. Of course I want to support undo for this text too, so I have the "Undo" checkmark enabled in Interface Builder for this NSTextView, and undo works just fine.

Now comes the rub: the NSDocument is getting marked as dirty when the NSTextView is modified. Because this is temporary text, I don't want the user to be nagged to save changes to the document, that really are not part of the document.

How do I detach the NSTextView from the responder chain leading up to the NSDocument's undo manager instance?  Simply providing a new instance of NSUndoManager doesn't solve it, because it just goes up the responder chain to NSDocument as well.

```
extension InputViewController: NSTextViewDelegate {
    func undoManager(for view: NSTextView) -> UndoManager? {
        return myUndoManager
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. Is the delegate connected/set? Is `undoManager(for:)` called? Please post a [mre].

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, I simply used it to express what I mean by "providing a new instance of NSUndoManager"

Comment: The document is not getting marked as dirty. Simply providing a new instance of NSUndoManager does solve it. What is the problem?

Comment: Well, well. I retested this, and lo and behold, this works fine. I had the answer all along. Thank you for persisting to nudge me on this.

Comment: ..however, it breaks the settings view controller's undo manager. I really want just one undo manager here, and thus I went with the answer below, using the `updateChangeCount` override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'd need to override the `undoManager` property of the window's view controller, not the text field's delegate.

However, to simply make your document/window permanently non-editable all you need to do is override either the `documentEdited` property so it always returns `false`, or override `updateChangeCount` so it ignores requests to record changes.

Comment: I still want the document to go dirty when edited by the settings view controller. What I want to do is dettach the temporary text NSTextView undo manager from making NSDocument dirty. Essentially changing the responder chain for the NSTextView.

Comment: I've never tried to fiddle with the undo manager for a single view (only docs and windows), but I would suspect the view is getting its undo manager from the `NSTexField` or `NSTextView` and not the delegate. The doc for `NSResponder` says is it "simply invokes this property on the next responder" so you might intercept the `undoManager` on the window (just for debugging), set a breakpoint, and see if you can trace the call chain from whence it got there. That could give you some insight on where to intercept it.

Comment: Well, here's what's going on, from the documentation for NSDocument.addWindowController():

"An NSDocument object uses its list of window controllers when it displays all document windows, sets window edited status upon an undo or redo operation, and modifies window titles [...]"

This means that any view controller's undo managers will be tied into the responder chain. I'm still left with the puzzle of how to exclude the one view controller I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: "or override updateChangeCount so it ignores requests to record changes."

Yeah, that's the direction I'm going to have to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to James Bucanek's comment about overriding `updateChangeCount`, I was able to do something like this in my `NSDocument` subclass:

```
    override func updateChangeCount(_ change: NSDocument.ChangeType) {
        if !suppressChangeCount {
            super.updateChangeCount(change)
        } else {
            suppressChangeCount = false
        }
    }
```

Thus allowing undo/redo to work in my `InputViewController` keycode handler without dirtying the document.